# Adding notes to a custom form

Tags: theming, forms

I have created a custom form and have put in some notes but I am wondering whether it's the correct 'Drupal' way. I have added the notes using the following format:

```
  $form['notes'] = array(
    '#markup' => 'A few notes. 
      <ul>
        <li>Item i</li>
        <li>Item ii</li>
        <li>Item iii</li>
         <ul>'
   )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the preinstalled theme `item_list`:

```
  $form['notes'] = [
    '#theme' => 'item_list',
    '#title' => $this->t('A few notes.'),
    '#list_type' => 'ul',
    '#items' => ['Item i', 'Item ii', 'Item iii'],
  ];
```

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21item-list.html.twig/8.5.x

Comment: This is useful if you don't want to have control over the markup (or don't have to override the annoying `item-list` styles the core themes add). The minute you want to, say, change the title's tag you'll need something custom

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if there's such a thing as a 'Drupal' way for something like this, it's theming.

Add a theme item in your module/theme:

```
function MODULE_theme() {
  return [
    'MODULE_notes' => [
      'variables' => ['title' => NULL, 'items' => []],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Add a template at templates/MODULE-notes.html.twig:

```
{{ title }}
<ul>
{% for item in items %}
  <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And then use it:

```
$form['notes'] = [
  '#theme' => 'MODULE_notes',
  '#title' => 'A few notes',
  '#items' = [
    'Item i',
    'Item ii',
  ],
];
```

Obviously there are many things you could do to augment the way that works depending on your exact requirements.